# Error al intentar consumir un .svc desde ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Tengo que consumir un servicio web  ***(.svc)*** desde  una aplicación *ASP.NET*. La parte de servidor no puedo modificarla. En ***Visual Studio***, al agregar la referencia de servicio, no se me está generando en el **web.config**, la sección `<system.Servicemodel>`, y no sé por qué.

El caso es que he decidido crearla manualmente. Entonces, en la parte del servidor, la configuración es:

```
<services >
   <service name="RestService.RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint bindingConfiguration="webHttpTransportSecurity" address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestService.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpTransportSecurity">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
```

Y en mi cliente, creado manualmente, tengo:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://URL servicio .svc" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpTransportSecurity" contract="GEDService.IRestServiceImpl"
            name="RestService.RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
</client>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpTransportSecurity"/>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

El caso es que al intentar consumir cualquiera de los métodos expuestos por el servicio, me está tirando el siguiente error:

> El esquema de URI proporcionado 'https' no es válido; se esperaba 'http'. Nombre del parámetro: via

No veo que haya error en mi configuración. Entonces, ¿Por qué sucede esto y cómo se soluciona?

Comment: Has probado a consumir el endpoint con http://? `<endpoint address="http://URL servicio .svc" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpTransportSecurity" contract="GEDService.IRestServiceImpl"
            name="RestService.RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Por el tema del https/http fijate si el WS solo acepta HTTP, si es asi cambia tu codigo donde dice

```
<serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
```

por

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
```

también este otro en el cliente

```
<binding name="webHttpTransportSecurity"/>
```

por este otro

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding"/>
```

Por otro lado, es raro que no te genere el ServiceModel en el web.config. Estas seguro que tomaste el url hasta el .wsdl? Fíjate que si entras al .svc por el browser se ven unos links para obtener la especificación correcta (es un archivo xml) que luego puedes importar en Visual Studio para que te autogenere el código.

Saludos!

Comment: Buenas, lo primero de todo mil gracias por contestar. He podido acceder a la configuración del servicio publicado y sólo admite peticiones https, eso ya lo tengo claro. He alineado la configuración de mi cliente (manualmente, como digo Visual Studio no me lo genera)  con la del servidor y ahora ya no me salta ese mismo error, me está generando, al intentar cualquier método expuesto un error 405, diciendo que el método no está permitido. Estoy buscando información relativa a ese error, veremos.

Comment: Buenisimo. Con respecto al error 405 puede ser que estes haciendo la peticion por Get pero el svc acepta solo un Post para esa funcion. Otra opcion es que neccesites autenticarte primero o bien es un tema de CORS (el servidor no acepta requests de tu ip/dominio)

Answer (score -1):

Has verificado tu archivo host?

En caso de que el webservice requiera usar una VPN para poder utilizarlo entonces debes modificar ese archivo para que tu computadora pueda reconocer la url/ip.

Espero este link sea de utilidad: [link](https://www.ionos.mx/digitalguide/servidores/configuracion/archivo-hosts/).